# Python loop using three variables from lookup table

Tags: python, python-3.x

Please bear with me as I'm still learning Python. I'm trying to think of a way to build a loop using multiple rows of three variables from a lookup table.

The lookup table contains a numbered index and the three variables split into columns. There is about 290 rows, each row represents one loop that I'm targeting.

My python script is working, but i'll have to copy/paste code for 290 items. Is there a way to somehow build a loop that sources three variables from a lookup table?

Example Lookup Table:

[image]

Python Script:

```
import pandas as pd
import os, shutil
import numpy as np

# Import Lookup Table
# Can this table be used as a lookup for loop variables myfile, pname, and ename?
DF_LU = 'E:/Python Projects/ParmAudit/LUParm.csv'

# Source and Export Directories
sourcedir = 'E:/Python Projects/ParmAudit/Dump/'
exportdir = 'E:/Python Projects/ParmAudit/Export/'

# cbrs_alarm

# These variables change based on each row from the lookup table 
myfile = 'N_1.txt'
pname = 'cbrs_alarm_threshold'
ename = 'cbrs_alarm_threshold.csv'

# Remove 1st row for clean csv file
with open(os.path.join(sourcedir, myfile)) as f:
    lines = list(f)

lines.pop(0)  # delete 1st row

# Write lines back into file
with open(os.path.join(sourcedir, myfile), "w") as f:
    for line in lines:
        f.write(line)

#Create dataframe
DF = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(sourcedir, myfile))
#Add column to dataframe
DF['STA_Parm'] = pname
#Set new column as the first column
first_column = DF.pop('STA_Parm')
DF.insert(0, 'STA_Parm', first_column)

#Export DF to CSV
DF.to_csv(os.path.join(exportdir, ename), index=False)


# acdc_profiles

myfile = 'N_3.txt'
pname = 'acdc_profiles'
ename = 'acdc_profiles.csv'

with open(os.path.join(sourcedir, myfile)) as f:
    lines = list(f)

lines.pop(0)

# Write lines back into file
with open(os.path.join(sourcedir, myfile), "w") as f:
    for line in lines:
        f.write(line)
        
DF = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(sourcedir, myfile))
DF['STA_Parm'] = pname
first_column = DF.pop('STA_Parm')
DF.insert(0, 'STA_Parm', first_column)
#display(DF)
DF.to_csv(os.path.join(exportdir, ename), index=False)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `csv` module to loop through the CSV file, assigning the variables from each column of the file.

```
with open(DF_LU) AS lu_file:
    lu_csv = csv.reader(lu_file)
    for LU_index, myfile, pname, ename in lu_csv:
        # your code here
```